# jQuery not working inside of additional tags

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to 'aim' my JavaScript code towards a particular piece of code and I'm almost there but fallen down at the last hurdle!

I've created a fiddle of what I'm trying to create here;

http://jsfiddle.net/k4mLb14n/1/

```
       <div class="pricing-levels-3">
      <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
      <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
    </div>

   <div class="pricing-levels-3">
      <p><strong>Which level would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
      <label><input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1</label><br>
      <label><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2</label><br>
      <label><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3</label><br>
      <label><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4</label><br>
      <label><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5</label><br>
      <label><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6</label><br>
      <label><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7</label><br>
    </div>
```

So basically I want to create a checklist and limit the amount of items that you can select, in my fiddle I've got the first list exactly how I want it - you can only select 3 items but in the second list you can select as many as you want.

The only difference is that the second list is check boxes are in `<label>` tags which is how I want to structure the code but this breaks my javascript.

So I want to adjust my javascript here so that it works for the second list;

```
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
this.checked = false;
}
});
```

Any advice welcome!

Comment: you can just go one level up and select all children checkboxes `$(this).parents('.pricing-levels-3').find('input.single-checkbox:checked')`

Comment: @AbdoAdel `.parents` is not a good option here. It's a greedy method and it goes up until it hits the ceiling.

Comment: that's very correct, thanks @undefined ,  I didn't notice the answer when I was typing, shall I assign you some value as a way to thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using the `closest` method:

```
if ($(this).closest('.pricing-levels-3').find(':checked').length > limit) {
   this.checked = false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k4mLb14n/2/